# cannot search any picture with the app coded by myself

Tags: android

I tested the code on a MeiZu mobile phone. The code runs smoothly, but it shows "cannot search any pic".
My mobile phone has some pictures, so I want to ask why this is happening.

Here is my code:

mainactivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView_name;
    private TextView textView_count;
    private Set<String> dirPaths=new HashSet<String>();
    private int MaxCount;
    private File  MaxdirPath;
    private Handler handler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            iuni();
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView_name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_name);
        textView_count= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_count);
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SearchPicture();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void iuni() {
        if(MaxdirPath==null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"cannot search any pic！",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        textView_name.setText(MaxdirPath.getName());
        textView_count.setText(MaxCount+"");
    }

    private void SearchPicture() {
        if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Uri uri= MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            ContentResolver cr=this.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor=cr.query(uri,null,MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE+"=? or "+MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE+"=?",new String[]{"image/jpeg","image/png"},MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            File parentFile=new File(path);
            if(parentFile==null){continue;}
            String dirPath=parentFile.getAbsolutePath();
            if(dirPaths.contains(dirPath)){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                dirPaths.add(dirPath);
                if(parentFile.list()==null){
                    continue;
                }
                int count=parentFile.list(new FilenameFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                        if(filename.endsWith(".jpg")||filename.endsWith(".png")||filename.endsWith("jpeg")){
                            return  true;
                        }
                        return  false;
                    }
                }).length;
                if(count>MaxCount){
                    MaxCount=count;
                    MaxdirPath=parentFile;
                }
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x110);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/id_name"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id_count"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First check that did you get data in cursor or not? If you are not getting any data in cursor then you would not be able to search, so check it .

Comment: Thank you for you advise. I test the code,I see the cursor loop 234 times,but just cannot find any pic. thany you all the same.

Comment: I can't immediately see what's the problem, but I'll share one small optimisation tip: move the initialisation of the FilenameFilter out of the loop - it'll work just as well and you won't have to recreate it (and make more garbage to be collected) every iteration. Happy bug hunt!

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode and stepped through the execution line by line (set a breakpoint)? Then you can see when (or rather if) it gets into the `if(count>MaxCount)` block. Technically, if it gets there (and `parentFile != null`) it should work...

Comment: when  test the code again,I find a interesting thing. the code loops  into (parentFile.list()==null),then continue, next into (parentFile.list()==null),again and again.It never go to(count>MaxCount) .

Comment: my photoes cannot be queried .That is amusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem now.

```
String path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
File parentFile=new File(path); 
(...)
if(parentFile.list()==null){
```

The `File parentFile` looks like it's actually the file itself, and not the parent (directory). Therefore `parentFile.list()` returns null as a regular file cannot have files in it.

If you instead do something like this, I think it should work:

```
File currentFile = new File(path);
File parentFile = currentFile.getParentFile();
(...)
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Of course the calls could be chained so you wouldn't need the intermediate `currentFile` object - `parentFile = new File(path).getParentFile();`

Comment: Also if it worked then you should consider marking it as the accepted answer, so other people looking for the same can quickly see what worked for you. :) (Seeing as the question has been upvoted, there are probably someone else wondering about the same thing)

Comment: Do you mean to click  your  answer  in your conmment title ?  I have done it.

Comment: No, there should be a check mark under the up-/downvote buttons (empty, turns green when clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your cursor to first position before using it. Only after that, you can navigate thru its content.

Otherwise, `cursor.moveToNext()` will return `false`.

Try to change your code to something like:

```
private void SearchPicture() {
    ...

    Cursor cursor=cr.query(uri,null,MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE+"=? or "+MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE+"=?",new String[]{"image/jpeg","image/png"},MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you advise.I had do what you teld,but it didnot do for my question.and then I test the code,I see the cursor loop 234 times,but just cannot find any pic. thany you all the same.